# Download a file with a parameter in URL

Tags: apache, url, download

I noticed that downloading a file on a Apache server with:

```
example.com/myfile.zip?parameter=2365
```

gives exactly the same result / same downloaded file / same downloaded filename on client browser as downloading:

```
example.com/myfile.zip
```

**Is it a supported and documented feature of Apache?**

I am happy with it, and this will be useful for tracking purposes (I can ship download links with parameters `?source=email` and then I will be able to see the parameter in Apache logs, this is useful!), but I wanted to be sure it will work on all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, etc.)

*Note: Are we sure that on most browsers, the downloaded file will have filename `myfile.zip` and not `myfile.zip<somechar>parameter=2365`? I tried `wget example.com/myfile.zip?parameter=2365` and unfortunately the filename on disk is `myfile.zip?parameter=2365`, so it doesn't work well with `wget`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), if there's nothing configured to analyse the parameters then the server will just return the file.

As you've noticed, the Apache logs will include this information if they are configured to. It's perfectly safe to use that syntax, it is defined as part of the [URI specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).

Comment: Thanks. What is the configuration option we should set in Apache conf file to see these `?parameter=1234` in logs?

Comment: Please ask a new question for this, that's not what you originally asked. The [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) has plenty of information on how to do this

Comment: Ok. I thought it would just be adding 1 or 2 lines to this answer.

Comment: Do you think it's sure @arco444, that the downloaded file will have this filename `myfile.zip` and not `myfile.zip<somechar>parameter=2365` on most browsers? (Chrome, FF, etc. and even `wget`)

Comment: Depends how you download it. Set the `Content-Disposition` header if you want to force the filename. You'll have no control over whatever is downloading it will honor the value, however.